# How to make VLC video look like media player classic

Tags: video, vlc-media-player

So I'm using VLC for a long time but picture attributes on MPC look better.Due to some personal preferences, I don't want to switch to MPC but I do want to make its pic look like MPC.Any way I can do that?

Picture comparison for reference:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Open `Video effects...` from the `Window` menu. From there you can apply settings to alter video playback. The `Basic` tab has, among others, options for hue, saturation, contrast and gamma. You can adjust these to your own liking and save them as a default or as a selectable profile.